# Trying to get gradient to sticky to the bottom of <body>

Tags: css

I am trying to get my gradient to sticky to the bottom of the page. It will work ok if the content requires scrolling ... http://jsfiddle.net/wDAQH/1/

but when the content is very short, it needs to stick to the bottom of the page, how can I acheive it? `html, body { min-height: 100%; }` doesn't seem to do the trick http://jsfiddle.net/wDAQH/2/

How can I get the gradient to the bottom of the content or screen whichever is larger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try sticky footer - http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ .

I used it on different projects and never had problems.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `body:after` with `html`

```
html {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 120px;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0), #d6d6d6);   
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/wDAQH/6/

**Another way you can do it is** Put a `<div>` wrapper around the `<p>` tags, Add `height:100%` to your `html,body` tags, remove `body:after` And finally add the following div properties to your CSS

```
div{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0), #d6d6d6);   
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/wDAQH/5/

Comment: for the 1st method, I did that b4, if the content is too long like http://jsfiddle.net/wDAQH/7/ the gradient will be at the wrong place. Is there a way to fix this? The same problem in method 2 also. I'd prefer the 1st method as it does not use extra markup